# ajaxExtended call Failed error in azuure bot services

Tags: azure, bots, botframework

I have encountered "ajaxExtended call failed" error when tried to create a bot using the Azure services. I don't have any SDK bot that I can migrate.

Provided the screenshot below.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9u40.png)

Comment: Could you please provide indication of what call is failing?
If you can reproduce the problem, collect a Fiddler/HTTP trace (you can also use the F12 dev tools in the browser) and see which request (likely a POST against dev.botframework.com) is failing.
Also, check the "Console" section of the browser dev tools for a possible XSS failure

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883255/ajax-extended-call-failed-in-azure/47893412#47893412

Comment: This is triggered when you don't have enough permissions to create Azure AD apps. Contact your Azure tenant admin to fix it.

Comment: @nilsw I don't believe it has to do with permissions. I run into this problem with my corporate and personal account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was trying to build a Web App Bot with the same name as one I'd recently deleted. I changed the name and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the permission .. in our case super admin was able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to configure access to a proxy (Windows settings --> Proxy).