# Failed to save Remote Desktop settings (Azure)

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure Cloud Service (classic) that I am trying to enable RDP access on. Enabling it requires having a username, password, and a preexisting encryption certificate. I supply all of the information for those fields, but receive an error "Failed to save Remote Desktop settings" with the following error: "Failed to update extensions for following rules DemoWorkerRole. ajaxExtended call failed". How do I resolve this error?

I'm assuming there is something wrong with my certificate - it's CN is the same as the cloud service's Site URL without the `http://` prefix and the `/` suffix.

Comment: Is your RDP configuration set up on the portal? Or is it set through Visual Studio? What is the version of Visual Studio, 2017 or 2019?

Comment: Many times, some problems are strange. Sometimes deleting resources, renaming and creating can solve this problem. You can try .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879679/ajaxextended-call-failed-error-in-azuure-bot-services

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was an incorrect RDP configuration, thank you Jason Pan!